# Multiply row of pandas dataframe based on column name, using values of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two `DataFrames`, as follows :

```
df1 = 


 name1 name2  name3   ....    nameXXX 
  5.1   1.2    1.1    ...      223.2
  3.22  1.34   1.5    ...      213.2
  4.3   1.32   1.23   ...      523.2
  5.2   1.1    1.543  ...      223.2

df2=

name1     0.2
name2     0.1
name3     0.43
...       ...
nameXXX   0.21
```

What I need :

df3=

```
 name1       name2         name3     ...         nameXXX 
5.1 * 0.2   1.2 * 0.1    1.1 * 0.43  ...      223.2 *  0.21
3.22* 0.2   1.34* 0.1    1.5 * 0.43  ...      213.2 * 0.21
4.3 * 0.2   1.32* 0.1    1.2 * 0.43  ...      523.2 * 0.21
5.2 * 0.2   1.1 * 0.1    1.54* 0.43  ...      223.2 *  0.21
```

- the `name`s are the column headers
- Basically I want to multiply each column of `df1` by the number present in `df2` that is in the same row of the column header of `df1`

I saw the following questions but I couldn't find the solution to my problem :

1) [How to select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

2)[Pandas: pairwise multiplication of columns based on column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53782147/pandas-pairwise-multiplication-of-columns-based-on-column-name)

3) [Multiply columns of a dataframe by getting the column names from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55042354/multiply-columns-of-a-dataframe-by-getting-the-column-names-from-a-list)

4)[pandas: Select dataframe columns based on another dataframe's columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46228574/pandas-select-dataframe-columns-based-on-another-dataframes-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `name` column is your index, you can just do

```
df1.mul(df2.iloc[:,0], axis='columns')
```

If it's is a normal column, you can set it as an index:

```
df1.mul(df2.set_index(0).iloc[:,0], axis='columns')
```

Output:

```
   name1  name2    name3  nameXXX
0  1.020  0.120  0.47300   46.872
1  0.644  0.134  0.64500   44.772
2  0.860  0.132  0.52890  109.872
3  1.040  0.110  0.66349   46.872
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us do

```
df1=df1.mul(df2,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to update the column, essentially if you have the same number of columns as rows in your other df, you can try:

cols = df1.columns
   for i in cols:
      df1[i] = df1[i] * df2.loc[i].values

Typing from phone sorry for formatting